# JSPs for a simple Project Reporting Web App?

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp

I'm about to start developing a simple reporting tool for tasks in international projects. In a nutshell: using the tool, a project is created, defining team members, tasks, and work packages. Team members will be asked to periodically submit reports on the work they've done (related to tasks and/or work packages). These reports will be stored and accessed trough the tool.

I'll use Google App Engine (client requirement) and its datastore (using JDO). But I want to ask you for advice on the frontend part: JSP looks pretty messy for non Java developers... any other idea???

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like at the moment it's either java or python. However, you may want to look at Grails. GSPs might looks a little less 'messy'. I'm suggesting Grails based on your description of the project, that I suspect will turn out anything but simple later on. You might end up being glad for the mix of constraints and flexibility that Grails will afford.

Answer (score 0):

JSP doesn't need to be any messier than other similar HTML presentation frameworks, it really comes down to implementation.  That being said, it is old Java technology which means it's not being kept up to date, and finding a good single source of documentation is difficult.

If you don't want to use JSP, there are other frameworks you can use, you just need to make sure they're compatible with Google App Engine.

The new kid on the block is the Play framework, and that's a Java MVC framework similar to Ruby on Rails.  You can find a tutorial here:  http://viralpatel.net/blogs/first-play-framework-gae-siena-application-tutorial-example/

If you're going to use Spring, check out this question:  [Alternatives to JSP for Spring MVC view layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746598/alternatives-to-jsp-for-spring-mvc-view-layer)

For a front end developer, if the code is separated correctly, you won't have to know anything about Java since there shouldn't be any Java mixed in with the HTML.  If that's your only worry, then I would just go with JSP to keep things simple unless the team has experience with another technology.